# Stylesheet is not loading in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer

Im trying to fetch the external CSS file in my angular application.
Path to the CSS file is decided by controller. But the CSS file is not loading in Internet explorer.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{css}}" media="all" />
```

In network tab, i can see the response code as 0 in IE Edge. But in IE 10 and below response code is coming as *Aborted*.

In other browsers like Chrome and firefox its working fine.

Comment: Try using the `angular-css-injector`; https://github.com/GabrielDelepine/angular-css-injector

Comment: Have you tried using `ng-href`?

Comment: @Nishant123 `ng-href` worked.