# Angular app on Microsoft Edge not loading CSS

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

My Angular app works perfectly on every browser but on Edge and IE it doesn't load CSS. It's hard to explain, because it loads, but doesn't work I don't know why.

As you can see:

[image]

The CSS is right there at head, but the app is like there's not CSS at all.

I added all the polyfills needed and this metatag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

I googled a lot but all the solutions are about apps not working at all, my app works, just without CSS.

This is my Polyfills.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: Hi there did you try polyfills.js there will be some commented code you should uncomment that. Between are you using yarn or npm?

Comment: @Eliotjse I just added my polyfills.ts, that's what I've found on other posts. I'm using npm

Comment: What is your Angular version? From your description, I guess it might be Angular<8. Is there any error in console in IE and Edge? You could check [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9) and followed the solution in it. Please make sure you have uncommented all the import lines in `polyfills.ts` and run `npm install --save classlist.js`, `npm install --save web-animations-js`. Besides, you could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883490/stylesheet-is-not-loading-in-internet-explorer) to see if you have the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Check your `browserlist` file, located at the root of the project. IE11 is typically not supported by default.

You will find this line that you'll have to change

```
not IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```